# How to impose D2 on gdc

Tags: d, gdc

I have installed GDC from the software center of ubuntu.

The problem is that when I tried to compile a source that contain the keyword `immutable`, it gives me an error. Then I deduced that it compiles only D1.

If i want to compile D2 with GDC, what should I do?

Comment: Pretty sure the packaged GDC for Debian/Ubuntu is D1 only and an old version of GDC at that.

Comment: That is correct. Ubuntu Maverick has the DMD-equivalent version 1.043 of GDC, and Natty has 1.063, according to packages.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-GDC/GDC) (warning: it's not yet complete in any shape or form).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm wrong or what you linked is only for windows?

Comment: @Marco: Sorry, I was referring to the source code. I'm not sure they have binaries for Linux.

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass **-v2** to select D2 compiling, e.g.:

```
gdc -v2 main.d
```

Answer (score 6):

The packages in the linux repository are very out of date.  To my knowledge, they are 
not compatible with D2 in any way.  I've tried.

The only way that I know how to get D2 working with GDC would be to compile GDC 
from here: https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/downloads

If you follow the instruction on the wiki, you can optionally compile it 
to work with D2.

I have recently switched from dmd to gdc using this method and have had no problems.
The code written and tested with dmd compiles cleanly with gdc.